# Configure Email to be sent on restoring a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-mail

Is there a way to configure Email in SQL Server such that an Email is sent when a particular database is restored.

Comment: Are you controlling when the database is restored?

Comment: This is a couple of lines with PowerShell.  I'd probably choose that route over trying to completely contain this within SQL Server.  With SMO, you can do a restore synchronously.  When that is complete fire off an email using the `System.Net.Mail` namespace.

Comment: You can't configure Database Mail to do this directly, but you *can* create a server-level trigger that calls the Database Mail stored proc. I do this on our live servers to notify the admin team of any databases that are either created or dropped. I did this a good while ago, so the details are fuzzy -- I think the only way to differentiate between a new database and a restored database is text searching the event XML.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: There is no server level trigger for DB restore

Comment: @TToni: I went back and looked at the code; it uses the `CREATE_DATABASE` event, so I tried it while restoring, and you're right, it doesn't fire either when a db is restored outright, or `WITH REPLACE`. I guess getting e-mailed when databases are *created* was enough for us. My bad.

Comment: @ShawnMelton: I would like to have notification via email when the db restore starts and completes.

Answer (score 2):

That's suprisingly difficult.

SQL Agent Alerts were the first stop, but because a restore doesn't generate an "error message" there is no way to trigger it (I tried message levels 1 and 10, but no banana). It might be possible with a WMI query, but I'm not proficient in that.

Policies and extended events can create the necessary conditions but have no way to alert you.

Audits don't have the necessary conditions.

So, brute force then. The "restoring ..." message goes into the SQL Server log and into the Windows application event log with source `MSSQLSERVER` and event id `3402`.

Working with that, you can attach a task to that event - unfortunately without having the option to filter based on the text which you need for the database name filter. So, configure the task to start a powershell script which then reads all the "MSSQLSERVER, 3402" events in , say, the last 2 minutes from the application log (hopefully you don't have mass restores all the time), checks for the correct db name and sends an email to you if it finds one with the wanted name.

As I said, brute force, but works.

Answer (score 2):

The `AUDIT_BACKUP_RESTORE_EVENT` from [Event Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190655.aspx) can be used, but the only catch is that it fires on backup/restore start.

`sys.dm_exec_requests` DMV has a column `command` that can be queried for **RESTORE DATABASE** in order to watch for restore session to complete.

Another way is to periodically query

- Default trace for EventClass = 115 AND TextData LIKE '%RESTORE%' as Aaron points out [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17115/8783).
- `msdb.dbo.restorehistory` for new databases that are restored.