server side trigger for after restoring database
there is a brilliant script to create a server side trigger on an event of a create database.
here is the script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM sys.server_triggers WHERE name = 'ddl_trig_database')
BEGIN
    DROP TRIGGER ddl_trig_database
    ON ALL SERVER;
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER ddl_trig_database 
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR CREATE_DATABASE 
AS 
    DECLARE 
        @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128)
        , @CreatedBy NVARCHAR(128)
        , @CreatedDate NVARCHAR(23)
        , @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);

    SELECT 
        @DatabaseName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]','NVARCHAR(128)')
        , @CreatedBy = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]','NVARCHAR(128)')
        , @CreatedDate = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]','NVARCHAR(23)');

    IF @DatabaseName = 'MyTestDatabase'
    BEGIN

    SET @SQL = '
        USE ' + @DatabaseName + ';
        EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''Owner'', @value = N''' + @CreatedBy + ''';
        EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''StartDate'', @value = N''' + @CreatedDate + ''';';

    -- PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC (@SQL);
    END

GO

CREATE DATABASE MyTestDatabase;
GO

SELECT name, value 
FROM MyTestDatabase.sys.fn_listextendedproperty(default, default, default, default, default, default, default)


DROP TRIGGER ddl_trig_database
ON ALL SERVER;
GO

DROP DATABASE MyTestDatabase;
GO

here is the result:

Now one thing I would like to achieve is having that same, but triggered when I restore a database on the server.
I have been looking around and I found a couple of options:

put a trigger on msdb - table msdb..restorehistory - which is not of my liking particularly, and restore filelistonly and the like should also be taken apart.
I could use event notification, but It seems lots of work involved

question:
is there a easier and cleaner way - to trigger some actions just after a database restore finishes?
I am mostly using sql 2019. what I really wanted is a server side trigger that fires when a database is restored.

You might want to check Aaron Bertrand's answer on this page, if haven't checked already. That seems helpful and less work than putting in an event notification.
[link] https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17103/automatically-execute-stored-procedure-after-any-restore-database-event
